# Vue.js - Images in imported CSS are not displayed

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

My project has the following structures:

```
-src
  -components
    - first
       - Base.vue (*)
  - refer
    - css
      - common
         - common.1.0.1.css (* Imported)
    - images
      - common
```

And I'm having trouble loading images defined in CSS file.

After importing the following css file in  tag:
`@import '../../refer/css/common/common.1.0.1.css';`

Styles other than images seem to be applied correctly.

For example, they style below does not apply the backgound-image...

```css
#bottom .bottom .container .content {
  background-image: url('./refer/images/common/bottom-logo.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #CBCBCB;
}
```

This also makes me think that there is some issue with the url path again...
please help me out!

Comment: what type of rules do you have for image files in your webpack config? such as url loader or file loader

Comment: Right now all I have is `vue.config.js` file in the root folder. ```module.exports = {

    productionSourceMap: false,
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            less: {
                javascriptEnabled: true
            }
        }
    }
}```

Comment: Try to import the css file in your js insted.

Comment: Have you tried:
background-image: url('./.../refer/images/common/bottom-logo.png');

Comment: Nope... it's not wokring :(